# How to get text between two texts with Regex on BUILD_LOG_REGEX in Jenkins

Tags: regex, jenkins

I'm trying to get the version of the app from the jenkins log to send it to email.

The log (part of it) is:

```
[INFO] Image 03127cdb479b: Layer already exists
[INFO] Image 9c742cd6c7a5: Layer already exists
[INFO] Image 1f8a8b50f407: Pushing
[INFO] Image 1f8a8b50f407: Pushed
[INFO] 4.2.3-202211071000: digest: sha256:[large_number] size: 2415
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want only the **4.2.3-202211071000** part, so I'm doing:

```
${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="(?<=\[INFO])(.*)(?=: digest)", maxMatches=1, showTruncatedLines=false, substText="$1"}
```

but this is returning the entire line:

```
[INFO] 4.2.3-202211071000: digest: sha256:[large_number] size: 2415
```

not only the text between "[INFO] " and ": digest". How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do that by using another token and matching using another line of the log:

```
${BUILD_LOG_MULTILINE_REGEX, regex="(?<=Building [NOME OF THE PROJECT] )(.*)", maxMatches=1, showTruncatedLines=false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `(?<=\[INFO\] )[-\d\.]+(?=:)`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/uQt2Y0/1) for a breakdown of the RegEx

Comment: It didnt work. It creates an empty text.

Comment: Interesting...I wonder if lookahead isn't supported? I'm not terribly familiar with Jenkins, I'm afraid. Perhaps you need to escape each of the backslashes, e.g. \\, but that's a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following pattern.

```
regex="(\\[INFO\\] (.*): digest)"
```